deploying a machine learning workspace - Missing dependent resources in workspace json
I have been completing some of the Microsoft learn modules for the data science career path. The first few modules went perfectly but today I have been receiving errors when trying to complete new modules. I then went back to complete old modules and the new error is now appearing there as well. Any help is appreciated.
I have been following this tutorial and inputted the two chunks of code that appear in the tutorial into the azure power shell. I then get the errors that are included here error image. I was expecting the code to successfully create a machine learning workspace in my azure resource group.

Where is the error message?

apologies I have included it now

Please provide the error message in text format.

I am able to create the resource without any issues.

Refer this MSQ&A Once
